# Is it possible to trigger TravisCI build by Slack message w/o spinning up my own server?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, slack, slack-api

When I did research online, most of the solutions are about triggering Slack notification from TravisCI. Now I want to do the reverse direction - type some message in slack, and trigger a build task in TravisCI.

I'm looking at Slack's Outgoing WebHooks - under their "Custom Integrations" in Slack app directory. However, their webhook POST data spec is fixed, not seem to be programmable through just their webpage UI. They have a column in the UI that lets you fill in URL(s) to POST to. But I don't see any ways that I can customize the data field of the POST request.

Same as TravisCI's [Triggering Builds API v3](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/), the data fields they expect in the POST are fixed and unchangeable.

I know I can sign up a cloud service, write some code and spin up a server to re-package the parameters to do the work, like a middleware between these 2 APIs. But just want to see if anyone manages to achieve triggering TravisCI by Slack in such way that doesn't involve spinning up a server myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hosting a server and writing the porting logic myself. I guess there's no simple way to do this, after all they are different APIs. [Here is the code where I request against travisCI API](https://github.com/rivernews/slack-middleware-server/blob/467919ddd1a237c1276311890e820678c08a6822/server/services/travis.js#L21), and [here is the code where I unpack the slack webhook POST request](https://github.com/rivernews/slack-middleware-server/blob/467919ddd1a237c1276311890e820678c08a6822/server/services/slack/slack.js#L50-L60).